# WebBrowser control wrapped in a custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, class

I'm quite new to C# and .NET in general so this may seem like a silly question? I'm trying to follow this advice [here](http://css.dzone.com/news/disable-javascript-error-wpf)

I need some help on what exactly is meant by the statement "First of all I have my WebBrowser control wrapped in a custom class to add functionalities, in that class I declare this constant....."

At the moment I have the WPF Webbrowser Control manually added as in the XAML below

```
<Window x:Class="ProjectX.WebbrowserWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="WebbrowserWindow" Height="378" Width="632">
    <Grid>
        <WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,32,0,0" Name="webBrowser1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Navigated="webBrowser1_Navigated" />
        <Button Content="Go!" Height="22" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="507,3,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="78" Click="button1_Click" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,2,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="497" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm assuming I just need to create a new class (say WebBrowserCustom.cs) and add those events? But I'm struggling to understand how I then add it to a WPF window?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need some help on what exactly is meant by the statement "First of all I have my WebBrowser control wrapped in a custom class to add functionalities, in that class I declare this constant....."

It's just a user control.  Which, in your code, will inherit from `UserControl`.  There are countless examples out there.  You can get started on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514641%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) though, which is a great resource.  I even found a video [here](http://windowsclient.net/learn/video.aspx?v=76360) that would help you get started.  Once you create your control, which is essentially wrapping a `WebBrowser` control, you can expose events and properties from your `UserControl`.  I suggest you get started on the basics first though so you can understand what is going on.